Is any smooth function in some Gevrey class
The wikipedia entry for Gevrey classes states the following:

When $\displaystyle \sigma =1$, $\displaystyle G^{\sigma }(\Omega )$ coincides with the class of analytic functions $\displaystyle C^{\omega }(\Omega )$, but for $\displaystyle \sigma >1$ there are compactly supported functions in the class that are not identically zero (an impossibility in ${\displaystyle C^{\omega }}$). It is in this sense that they interpolate between ${\displaystyle C^{\omega }}$ and ${\displaystyle C^{\infty }}$.

Is $\displaystyle C^\infty(\Omega) = \bigcup _{\sigma \geq 1} G^{\sigma }(\Omega )$? My guess would be that this is not the case, but I cannot think of an counterexample, i.e. a function not contained in any Gevrey class.

Apply the Borel lemma with $\alpha _n  = n!^{n+1} $.

I'll work out the details using the hint/solution in the comments for the sake of closing this question.
Borel Lemma:
For every complex sequence $\alpha_n$ there exists a smooth function $f$ such that $f^{(n)}(0)=\alpha_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Now, let $f$ be as in the lemma for $\alpha_n = n!^{n+1}$ and suppose $f \in G^s(\mathbb{R})$ for some $s \geq 1$.
Take a compact set $K$ containing the origin and pick $C$ such that the Gevrey class constraint is fullfilled for this $K$.
We find
$$
n!^{n+1} = f^{(n)}(0) \leq \sup_{x \in K} |f^{(n)}(x)| \leq C^{n+1} (n!)^s, \qquad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}
.
$$
However, this would imply that
$$
n!^{1-\frac{s}{n+1}} \leq C, \qquad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}
,
$$
which of course does not hold.
Hence $\displaystyle f \in  C^\infty(\Omega) \setminus \bigcup _{\sigma \geq 1} G^{\sigma }(\Omega )$.

Even more, there is a Baire category strengthening: Frank Sydney Cater (1934-___), Most $C^{\infty}$ functions are nowhere Gevrey  differentiable of any order, Real Analysis Exchange 27 #1 (2001-2002), pp. 77-79. [Note: The version at Project Euclid is pp. 77-80, but this appears to be a not-quite final version, as the print version is pp. 77-79 -- I'm looking at a hard copy of issue 27 #1 right now.]
